# HTML 5 localStorage feature stopped working suddenly in my Phonegap app for IOS

Tags: javascript, php, html, cordova, local-storage

Actually this app has been developed using the Phonegap. It is not a native IOS Application. You can get more information about Phonegap from the official site http://phonegap.com.

As you know we use HTML, CSS, JAVACRIPT in a Phonegap Application, so we are using an HTML 5 feature of local storage in our application in order to save some local data.

Like I did in login page. I sent a request to server with the login details using AJAX and if the login details are valid then the server sends a user id as a JSON response.

I saved that user id using HTML 5 local storage feature like below:

user_id=data['user_id'];   // the array data is the array that was generated from JSON response

window.localStorage.setItem("user_id",user_id);​  //saved user id in local storage

The above code saves the Id of the user in the local storage who is currently logged into the app.

But I am unable to retrieve that information from the local storage on the next page when I tried to retrieve it using the following code:

user_id = window.localStorage.getItem("user_id");​  // fetch user id from local storage

it saves "undefined" in variable user_id.

On the inner pages of app I have to send this user_id to the server after fetching it form the local sotrage in order to get the data of the logged in user as a JSON resonponse from the server. But rather than sending actual user id it is sending "undefined" in place of that user_id to the server because of which the server doesn't generate proper JSON response and the AJAX gives an error callback where I am showing this message as an alert:
"Application could not reach doggone server. Please check your internet connection."

The strange thing is that it was working earlier when users purchased the app from app store and it stopped working suddenly when i tried to submit the new build for the next version of the app.

I did some research on google and I found that HTML 5 local storage doesn't work on IOS 5.1 or later. But it was working few days earlier. It stopped working since I am trying to upload the new binary for next version 2.0.

Kindly look at it this problem and provide a solution to us. Our whole app is using the HTML 5 local storage feature almost on every page  in order to fetch the current user data from server.

Comment: I would put in a check to make sure that `data['user_id']` is not `Undefined` just to be safe. It could be that your ajax call is nolonger returning the data how you expect.

Comment: success:function(data){

user_id=data['user_id'];

window.localStorage.setItem("user_id",user_id);

window.location.href="menu.html";

}

above is my code for ajax success callback.
its returning proper data.
after storing data into the local storage its redirecting to menu.html page.

infact its working perfectly on the android.

Answer (score 0):

put the

```
window.localStorage.setItem("user_id",user_id);​
```

in a try/catch block. You might easily catch a QUOTA_EXCEEDED error (ran out of storage space). Happened to me just the other day...